# Bug in RegionMember?

Tags: bugs, geometry, regions

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and have been fixed before 13.3.1**

 *`RegionMember` is new in 10.0*

 A commenter notes that the issue is with `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonTriangulate[polygon] ``

---

`RegionMember` (new in V10) appears to have a bug. For some polygons it finds points that are clearly outside to be "members" of the region. This depends on the shape of the polygon in a way that is hard to pin down. Here is one example.

```
polygonPoints = {{0, 200},{100, 200},{100, 300},{200, 300},{200, 
400},{250, 400},{250, 0},{200, 0},{200, 100},{0, 100}};
polygon = Polygon[polygonPoints];
polyQ = RegionMember[polygon]

testPoints = Table[{300 Random[], 450 Random[]}, {10000}];
```

Next let's see which test points `RegionMember` finds to be inside the test polygon (blue points) and how it compares to actual polygon (gray region).

```
ListPlot[{testPoints, Select[testPoints, polyQ],polygonPoints}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, {PointSize -> Large, Green}}, Prolog -> {Gray, polygon}]
```

[image: A polygon and the points deemed to be inside it by RegionMember]

Changing the polygon reveals a little bit about how the bug affects results in this particular case. The mistaken area appears to be below a line that connects two vertices; moving one of the vertices and redoing the test confirms this.

```
polygonPointsB = ReplacePart[polygonPoints, 1 -> {0, 150}];
polygonB = Polygon[polygonPointsB]
polyBQ = RegionMember[polygonB]

ListPlot[{testPoints, Select[testPoints, polyBQ], polygonPointsB},   
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, {PointSize -> Large, Green}}, Prolog -> {Gray, polygonB}, 
 Epilog -> {Green, Thick, Line[polygonPointsB[[{1, 4}]]]}]
```

[image: A polygon and the points deemed to be inside it by RegionMember]

Other observations based on a small number of cases (using V10.3):

1. The mistaken region was always inside the convex hull of the actual polygon
2. Problem goes away when using real numbers to define the polygon

Comment: With `polygonPoints = N@polygonPoints` works well.

Comment: `polyQ // InputForm` reveals a difference between the exact and machine precision versions. For the latter it uses a MeshRegion, but for the former it contains an implicit member function which is presumably not quite correct.

Comment: The incorrect result in the exact case is coming from an internal triangulation routine, `Graphics\`PolygonUtils\`PolygonTriangulate[polygon]`.

Comment: @ilian What a horrible bug. Has this issue been reported to WRI?

Comment: @AliHashmi Ok I just reported it.

Comment: This bug still persists in v13 .0 . The old test code results in otherwise identical output, including (by visual inspection) the graphs, but there is now an error message in the middle, right after defining "polyQ" RegionMember function . Testing on two Linux machines gave apparently the same error message. The message is rather long, but only the last line looks substantially different from others. Here the first line:    Part::partw: Part 4294967297 of {{200.,100.},{200.,300.},{100.,300.},{100.,200.},{0.,200.},{0.,100.},{250.,0.},{250.,400.},{200.,400.},{200.,0.}} does not exist.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in v14.0

Answer (score 4):

This bug still exists in version 12.2.

**There is a workaround**, which uses an alternative method of creating the `RegionMemberFunction`. I've shown that below, but first let's look at a couple of other possibilities that don't pan out.

The first idea one might consider is to define an alternate region member function, as follows.

```
polyQ = RegionMember[polygon, #] &
```

This works, but it performs a couple orders of magnitude *slower* (presumably the reason `RegionMemberFunction` was invented), so it's not really an option.

Trying to fix the `RegionMemberFunction` directly doesn't work either, even though a workable repair seems apparent. Specifically, a `RegionMemberFunction` has three parts, the region specified in `RegionMember`, the dimensionality of the region (expressed as an integer), and a predicate (expressed as a pure `Function`). Given a point's coordinates, the predicate (part 3) returns `True` or `False`, according to whether or not the point lies in the region. In the cited case, evaluating and reducing the predicate makes the error clear (`y<=(400+x)/2` should be `y<=200`).

```
polyQ = RegionMember[polygon];
Reduce@polyQ[[3]][{x, y}]
```

> (0≤x<100 && 100≤y≤(400+x)/2) || (100≤x<200 && 100≤y≤300) || (200≤x≤250 && 0≤y≤400)

A correct predicate can be obtained as follows, where the expression here could be used as the body of a Function.

```
Element[(x|y),Reals] && Reduce@RegionMember[polygon,{x,y}]
```

> (x|y)∈ℝ && ((0≤x<100 && 100≤y≤200) || (100≤x<200 && 100≤y≤300) || (200≤x≤250 && 0≤y≤400))

However, replacing the predicate in a `RegionMemberFunction` with a corrected version makes no difference, because the predicate seems not to be used when `RegionMemberFunction` is applied. As constructed, this predicate apparently only *describes* what will happen, so changing it amounts to assigning the wrong description, and nothing more.

A corrected predicate *is* of use though in defining an `ImplicitRegion` for which `RegionMember` produces a valid (**and fast**) `RegionMemberFunction`.

```
polyQ=RegionMember@ImplicitRegion[Reduce@RegionMember[polygon,{x,y}],{x,y}]
```

> RegionMemberFunction[…]

The resulting `RegionMemberFunction` applies the correct predicate.

Moreover, the third part of the `RegionMemberFunction` describes correctly what the `RegionMemberFunction` will do.

```
polyQ[[3]][{x, y}]
```

> (x|y)∈ℝ && ((0≤x<100 && 100≤y≤200) || (100≤x<200 && 100≤y≤300) || (200≤x≤250 && 0≤y≤400))

This can be generalized in a fixed `RegionMember` function, as follows:

```
ClearAll@fixedRegionMember;

fixedRegionMember[reg_?RegionQ] := 
  RegionMember@ImplicitRegion[Reduce@RegionMember[reg, {x, y}], {x, y}];
```

Here is the result.

```
polyQ = fixedRegionMember[polygon]
```

> RegionMemberFunction[…]

```
With[{nPts = 10000},
 
 testPoints = Transpose@{RandomReal[{0, 300}, nPts], RandomReal[{0, 450}, nPts]};
 
 ListPlot[{testPoints, Select[testPoints, polyQ], polygonPoints}, 
    PlotStyle->{Red, Blue, {PointSize->Large, Green}}, 
    Prolog->{Gray, polygon}, ImageSize->Full] // AbsoluteTiming // Column
 ]
```

> [image: desired plot, with timing]